# Adding values contained in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I go about adding all the values within the object?

For example `amoutpay": ["4222","1000"]`  would give me `5222`

This is my object:

```
{
    "amoutpay": [ "4222", "1000" ],
    "amtpending": [ "778", "4000" ],
    "totalcost": [ "5000", "5000" ],
    "coursename": [ "Office Automation", "ajaba" ]
}
```

What I want is to add the values to variables. Would I use split?

```
var a =
var b =
var c =
```

Comment: You just need three loops, one each for `amountpay`, `amtpending` and `totalcost`. From there you can convert the string values to numbers and add them up. `split()` is not appropriate in this case as that's for turning a string in to an array. Also note that your question has nothing to do with JSON nor AJAX, so I removed the references to them.

Comment: how do i do that...  i know that it will count for each loop  but i want to know the syntax

Comment: really not json?  cause im catching these values through my ajax call to my php function which is returning print json_encode(variable);

Comment: Syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: @Marcos Pérez Gude what i meant was im not familiar with for loops in jquery certain syntax like hot do i get the count of the array  in php i  use count()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) as shown below:

```js
var obj = {
    "amoutpay": [ "4222", "1000" ],
    "amtpending": [ "778", "4000" ],
    "totalcost": [ "5000", "5000" ],
    "coursename": [ "Office Automation", "ajaba" ]
},
    
    a = obj.amoutpay.reduce(function(prevVal, curVal, curInd) {
        return +prevVal + +curVal;
    }),
    b = obj.amtpending.reduce(function(prevVal, curVal, curInd) {
        return +prevVal + +curVal;
    }),
    c = obj.totalcost.reduce(function(prevVal, curVal, curInd) {
        return +prevVal + +curVal;
    });

console.log( a, b, c );
```

Or you could go a step further and define your own array method, eg `Array.prototype.sum()`:

```js
var obj = {
        "amoutpay": [ "4222", "1000" ],
        "amtpending": [ "778", "4000" ],
        "totalcost": [ "5000", "5000" ],
        "coursename": [ "Office Automation", "ajaba" ]
    };

Array.prototype.sum = function() {
    return this.reduce(function( prv, cur, ind ) {
        return +prv + +cur;
    });
};

var a = obj.amoutpay.sum(),
    b = obj.amtpending.sum(),
    c = obj.totalcost.sum();

console.log( a, b, c );
```

Comment: Thanks That Helped

Comment: btw ind what value is that grabbing?   i dont see any use of  it inside the function

Comment: That's the current index. In this particular instance it's not required; you can safely leave it out. I just included it to show what parameters are passed - I know I should have said something about it, and you just gave me a chance to. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var obj = {
    "amoutpay": [ "4222", "1000" ],
    "amtpending": [ "778", "4000" ],
    "totalcost": [ "5000", "5000" ],
    "coursename": [ "Office Automation", "ajaba" ]
}

var a = addValues(obj.amoutpay);

function addValues(arr) {
    return arr.map(function(el) {
        return Number(el);
    }).reduce(function(prev, curr){
        return prev + curr;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We iterate the object elements and for all arrays we check whether all the elements are numeric. If so, then add them as variables to the `window` object, so after the loop we will have an `amoutpay` variable for the input shown in the question. Note, that if a `key` happens to already be a variable, then this code will override it.

```
for (var key in obj) {
    if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
        var shouldAdd = true;
        for (var index = 0; shouldAdd && index < obj[key].length; index++) {
            if (isNaN(obj[key][index])) {
                shouldAdd = false;
            }
        }
        if (shouldAdd) {
            window[key] = 0;
            for (var index = 0; index < obj[key].length; index++) {
                window[key] += parseFloat(obj[key][index]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```